# Rylai's Crystal Scepter on Vladimir

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, Rylai's Crystal Scepter seems like a great take for Vladimir, giving a large boost in both AP and health. But which of Vlad's abilities trigger the Scepter's slow effect? In particular I want to know if it works with Transfusion (Q).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rylai's is a decent pick on Vladimir, but ever since his nerf from his passive on the conversion of HP into AP I don't take it anymore and just focus on pure AP item like Rabadon's Deathcap.

But to answer the question, all of Vladimir's spells would proc Rylai's Unique ability, UNIQUE: Your spell damage slows the target's movement speed by 35% for 1.5 seconds (15% for multi-target spells and damage-over-time spells).

Which means, your transfusion would slow the target by 35% but the rest of your abilities since they are all AoE, multi-targeting spells, would only slow by 15%.

Comment: This is correct. Do bear in mind that Sanguine Pool already has a slow, which will (sort of) stack with the 15% Rylai's slow.

Comment: There might be a diminishing return though...

Comment: Yeah, that's the "(sort of)". There's a soft cap on slow effects, which based on the target's starting move speed, may or not be hit.

Comment: Hmm, got me interested so I posted a [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/how-are-all-diminishing-returns-calculated-in-league-of-legends).

Comment: @Raven I thought that slow does not stack or am I wrong?

Comment: @Drake Slows do stack, but there's a soft cap after which additional slows are less effective. Slows from *items* don't stack (Rylai's / Phage / Frozen Mallet).

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: There is [this thread](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/boards/showthread.php?t=189570) that mentions slow don't stack, is there are definitive evidence?

Comment: I've also seen some comments that Transfusion counts as an AoE for a few calculation purposes in terms of spell vamp and slow. Is this true for either?

Answer (score 0):

One of the notes on Vlad's [League of Legends wiki page](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vlad) indicates that Transfusion only slows 15% (possibly because it also targets Vlad?).

I don't know if that is accurate, however.

Answer (score 0):

Rylai's on Vlad works, but will only use the 15% slow, even for Transfusion (a single target nuke). Riot has said this is for balance purposes because of the cooldown on transfusion (Cassiopeia's twin fang also only applies 15% for the same reason).

I can't find the source for it, but I don't believe slows from the same characters don't stack, and slows from different characters apply (first slow + 60% second slow).

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, **when Vlad was initially released his Q (Transfusion) only applied a 15% slow** from Rylai's Crystal Scepter. This was a decision made and applied to the ability due to it's incredibly low cool-down and therefore possibility of a permanent slow on an enemy champion.

**As of the [Riven Patch](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=397106) (1.0.0.25, Sept 14 2011) his Q applies the full 35% slow of Rylai's.**