# how are movement speed modifies applied?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are all diminishing returns calculated in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/how-are-all-diminishing-returns-calculated-in-league-of-legends)

Stuff like which slows stack and how do they stack. Also do slows get applied before or after buffs cause it would make whichever is applied after better. Movement speed is a very core part of the game and how everything gets applied can be very confusing to figure out how to use all your utility the most effective way possible.

Comment: Hello, Illpalazzo! Your question is a duplicate, which means it has been answered elsewhere on the site (in the linked question). Therefore, closing this.

Answer (score 0):

Found on the [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed):

> (Base Movement Speed + Flat Movement Bonuses) × (1 + Percentage Movement Bonuses) × Slow Ratio

There are diminishing returns on bonus movement speed between 415 and 490(penalized at 80%) and an additional diminishing return on movement speed over 490(penalized at 50%.)

There is a lot more information available on the Wikia page I linked. It would not make sense for me to copy it all here, but the Wikia offers plenty of examples and scenarios. I strongly recommend reading it if you want a good education on how movement speed buffs/debuffs interact with each other.