# What are the maximum allowed stats?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are all diminishing returns calculated in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/how-are-all-diminishing-returns-calculated-in-league-of-legends)

I know that Cooldown Reduction is capped at **40%**, and Attack Speed at 2.5 (i.e. **+150%** to cap?). What are the various caps for all the equipment properties (life steal, armor, +%damage etc.), and which of these are limited to just a single source? (e.g. Rabadon's Deathcap gives +%AP, I'm not aware of any other item with this property).

Comment: Worth noting that it is not strictly "150% to cap" as far as AS goes - it strictly caps at 2.5 attacks per second, but not a strict value of +AS, as this is calculated differently per champion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember

- Critical strike : 100% cap
- Movement speed : [Edit] some cap applies see [Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed)
- Cooldown reduction : 40% cap
- Attack speed : 2.5 attacks per second cap

Most of these cap are surely confirm on the League of Legends wikia.