# Warwick attack speed questions

Tags: league-of-legends

I am wondering if it makes any sense to activate Warwicks <kbd>W</kbd> before I ult, it seems like the attack speed increase would have no affect. Better to activate after the ult is complete?

> ACTIVE: Warwick blinks to the front of an enemy champion and channels
>   for 1.5 seconds, suppressing the target for 1.8 seconds and dealing
>   magic damage 5 times in 1/3-second intervals. MAGIC DAMAGE PER HIT: 50
>   / 67 / 84 (+ 40% bonus AD) TOTAL DAMAGE: 250 / 335 / 420 (+ 200% bonus
>   AD) Warwick gains 30% life steal for the duration. Each damaging
>   strike applies on-hit effects, life steal, and maximum stacks of
>   Eternal Thirst

Also, what is the attack speed cap for Warwick? I noticed most Warwick builds contain Wits End (50%), BRK (40%), Feral Flare (30%) and then also Attack Speed runes (13.5%). Then you add his "W" to that as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

**Should I activate Warwicks W before ult?**

Well it won't help you. The ultimate has a fixed duration and only scales with AD and Magic Penetration. It can sometimes however be helpful if your ADC is around since your Ult is often used as a stun. Your teammates will have more attackspeed but in 1on1 situation you should activate it after the ult.

**What is the Attackspeed Cap for Warwick**

It's the same as for every champion. 2.5 Attacks per second. You can try to reach it but it's usually not a very viable build. If you have 1.5 attackspeed you will have more than enough if you are tanky aswell.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was trying to find time to do it (as I said in the comments). There is a question on ARQADE about AS too. If you could add that to your answer it would be great

Comment: Here is the link that I was looking for http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/how-are-all-diminishing-returns-calculated-in-league-of-legends

Comment: if you find this answer helpful, please mark it as an answer